# Linq to SQL Filter Matches

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, filter

I am familiar with basic queries in SQL, but I need to apply a filter and I'm not entirely sure how to go about it.

I current have this query:

```
var query = (from solvedPuzzle in db.SolvedPuzzles
              where solvedPuzzle.UserID == user.ID
              select solvedPuzzle);
```

And I want to modify the query or filter the results like this pseudocode:

```
for each pair (a,b) of results
  if a.PuzzleID == b.PuzzleID
     filter out a.NumberOfMoves > b.NumberOfMoves ? a : b
```

In case that isn't straightforward enough, I'll give example results of the filter

```
Table SolvedPuzzles:
ID   UserID    PuzzleID   NumberOfMoves
1    2         1          5
2    2         1          6   //Will be filtered out
3    2         2          7
4    3         1          8   //Will be filtered out
5    3         1          6
6    4         2          5
7    5         2          4
```

That is, those two will be filtered out of the results because they are by the same user and the same puzzle, but with a greater number of moves.

Comment: What would you expect to see if you had 3 records for the same user/puzzle combination? Or will they always be single or pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = (from solvedPuzzle in db.SolvedPuzzles
              where solvedPuzzle.UserID == user.ID
              order by NumberOfMoves ascending
              group solvedPuzzle by solvedPuzzle.PuzzleID into filtered
              select filtered.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you aren't actually looking for a *filter*, but a **min** value - in this case, the minimum number of moves for each unique combination of puzzle and user.

IN SQL this would be:

```
SELECT UserID, PuzzleID, MIN(NumberOfMoves) as UserMinForPuzzle
FROM SolvedPuzzles
GROUP BY UserID, PuzzleID
```

In linq this translates to a bit more complicated structure:

```
var query = (from sp in db.SolvedPuzzles
          where sp.UserID == user.ID
          group sp by new { sp.UserID, sp.PuzzleID } into g
          select new { 
             g.UserID, g.PuzzleID, Moves = g.Min(sp => sp.NumberOfMoves)
          };
```

Comment: This is correct, except with LINQ, it would be `g.Key.UserId` and `g.Key.PuzzleID`. Also, the `Where` on `UserId` means you can probably just group by `PuzzleID`.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right, I forgot the all important .Key under the grouped construct.